# Bad Request when sending Inline Picture as a MS Team Bot

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am receiving bad request when I including an attachment as an inline picture for the MS Teams Bot using the following code (the code works without attachments):

```
var message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.Text = "message here";
message.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
var webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData("https://img.icons8.com/windows/452/showing-small-size.png");
string url = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
{
    ContentType = "image/png",
    ContentUrl = url
});

var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
{
  IsGroup = true,
  ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
  {
      Channel = new ChannelInfo(outputChannelId),
  },
  Activity = (Activity)message
};

var response = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParameters);
```

I received the following error:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.CreateConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does that help provided by Hilton Giesenow clarify?

Comment: Hi Sridevi, is there any documentation that specify the possible reasons for bad request?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than including the image as an attachment, consider instead sending an Adaptive Card and you can display the image directly to the user. See more on Adaptive Cards [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-cards).

As an alternative if you don't want to *show* the image but it's hosted somewhere, just include a link to it in the text message, using the markdown format that regular text message support in Teams (see more [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772)).

Comment: Hi thanks! I would like to include it with the raw text instead of adaptive card. I am able to get the [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments/Bots/AttachmentsBot.cs) to work but I need to send it as a proactive message (using conversation.CreateConversationAsync).

Comment: Ah, in that case I think the problem is different. In Teams, the "conversation" exists already from the time the user installs your bot, so you don't use "CreateConversationAsync". Have a look at this sample for pro-active sending rather: https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/blob/main/samples/bot-proactive-messaging/src/dotnet-backend/Controllers/ProactiveSampleController.cs

Comment: The attachment process should then be the same as per the sample you sent, I think

Comment: thank you, Hilton. it appears that the picture and message are send separately.